# How connect client WebStorm to remote Java service in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, webstorm, angular-cli

I am working on a project that has client in Angular and server in Java. The Java services is developed in Java in Eclipse IDE but the client is developed on another machine with different IP and in WebStorm.

I do not know how can I connect Angular to the Java service and how to tell Angular that the required services is on another machine.

Comment: are you asking how this can be done in WebStorm, or you are not sure how to make your java server serve your Angular client app?

Comment: I do not know how this can be done in WebStorm?

Comment: create a javaScript Debug run configuration, specifying your server URL (the one you normally use to access your application in browser) as URL there. No magic